# Javascript statements parsed inside ng-repeat not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ngMap to populate a Google map with paired Markers and InfoWindows based on a list of objects `observations`. Following examples like [here](http://ngmap.github.io/#/infowindow_compile.html) but using my controller to generate the data. My `observations` have a lat/long position and a unique timestamp `created_at`. I'm using ng-repeat to create each pair of Marker and InfoWindow together with the same object, and using its timestamp to create a unique ID for the InfoWindow.

Each Marker's onClick handler should open the corresponding InfoWindow. However the result is that **each Marker opens a copy of the first InfoWindow** (but correctly anchored to the Marker that was clicked).

The view looks like this:

```
<ng-map center="United States" zoom="4">
    <marker
      ng-repeat-start="obs in gmap.observations"
      position="{{obs.latitude}},{{obs.longitude}}"
      on-click="gmap.map.showInfoWindow('info_{{obs.created_at}}')" />
    <info-window
      ng-repeat-end
      id="info_{{obs.created_at}}">
      <div ng-non-bindable="">
        <h3>{{obs.created_at}}</h3>
      </div>
    </info-window>
  </ng-map>
```

The data is populated here from a HTTP response, nothing special:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    $scope.gmap.observations = response.data.data;
    console.log("Loaded observations: " + $scope.gmap.observations.length);
}, function(err) { console.log("Error getting observations: " + err)});
```

And the resulting HTML in Firebug:

```
<marker class="ng-scope" on-click="gmap.map.showInfoWindow('info_1425398401044')" position="39.1948882,-106.8210516" ng-repeat-start="obs in gmap.observations" style=""></marker>
<info-window id="info_1425398401044" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="" style="display: none;">

<marker class="ng-scope" on-click="gmap.map.showInfoWindow('info_1425485573770')" position="39.194893,-106.8210517" ng-repeat-start="obs in gmap.observations"></marker>
<info-window id="info_1425485573770" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="" style="display: none;">

<marker class="ng-scope" on-click="gmap.map.showInfoWindow('info_1425485631669')" position="39.1949009,-106.8210548" ng-repeat-start="obs in gmap.observations"></marker>
<info-window id="info_1425485631669" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="" style="display: none;">

<marker class="ng-scope" on-click="gmap.map.showInfoWindow('info_1425924554521')" position="39.19467013,-106.82140428" ng-repeat-start="obs in gmap.observations"></marker>
<info-window id="info_1425924554521" class="ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="" style="display: none;">

...
```

As you can see, each marker has the correct unique ID parameter in its on-click callback, yet each will open the first InfoWindow with 1425398401044.

Answer (score 0):

I got around a similar problem with displaying latitudes and longitudes using a nested array. That way I was able to assign the position with just one variable.

In your example I would modify
`position="{{obs.latitude}},{{obs.longitude}}"`

to be

`position="{{obs}}"`

In the js file, change the obs array to contain tuples. Each tuple should have two numbers. The first number is the latitude, the second number is the longitude.

Comment: Geographic positioning works fine. It's opening the wrong window with the wrong element id at the correct position.